# Adding/using/concatenating "_" in filename

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a `_` between filename saving on VBA like:

```
    FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
            ComboBox1.Value & _
            & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xls"
```

And you can see I add the `& "_" &` to format this but it is not working. Can you please let me know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `&`.

Either remove the `&` from `ComboBox1.Value & _` or from `& "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xls"`

For example

```
FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
        ComboBox1.Value & _
        "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xls"
```

or

```
FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
        ComboBox1.Value _
        & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for some fun

```
FNAME = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
    Format(Date,make_name(ComboBox1.Value) & "_" & "ddmmmyyyy" & ".xl\s")

Function make_name(fname As String) As String
    Dim new_fname As String
    new_fname = StrConv(fname, vbUnicode)
    make_name = Left("\" & Join(Split(new_fname, vbNullChar), "\"), Len(new_fname))
End Function
```